# Conditional fetching with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, linq-to-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I need to eager load an object tree with NHibernate but I also wish to specify which objects to load.

The object tree is like this:

```
class A {
   double Date;
   IList<B> Bs;
}

class B {
   double Date;
   IList<C> Bs;
}

class C {
   double Date;
}
```

And what I want to do, is to eager load the whole tree, where A.Date > 2012, B.Date > 2012, C.Date > 2012 (basicly I want only a snapshot of the object tree according to my specified constraints).

Is that possible ?

I'm using NH 3.1 and Fluent.

Thanks!

Comment: what do the database tables look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with NHibernate Filters ? http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-filters